# Evaluating _react-native Animated Text.PropsTypes.style

Tags: react-native

I am new in React native and
I am trying to use react native material drop down
but im facing an issue

Evaluating _react-native Animated Text.PropsTypes.style

```
import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-material-dropdown'
var rbdagegroup = [
  { label: 'Adult', value: 'A' },
  { label: 'Junior', value: 'J' }
];

    export default class PersonalInfo extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
      }
      state = {
        AgeGroup: '',
      }
      render() {

        return (
         <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: '10%' }}>
    <TextInput
        placeholder="plac  "
        />
                  <Dropdown
                    value={this.state.AgeGroup}
                    data={rbdagegroup}
                    placeholder='Please select USTA Rating'
                    pickerStyle={{ borderBottomColor: 'transparent', borderWidth: 0 }}
                    dropdownOffset={{ 'top': 0 }}
                    containerStyle={{ width: '100%', marginRight: '10%' }}
                    inputContainerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 , paddingTop:"1%"}}
                    onChangeText={(AgeGroup) => {
                      this._SetAgeGroup({
                        AgeGroup
                      })
                    }}
                  />

          </View>
      );

      }

    }
```

how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by commenting itemTextStyle: Text.propTypes.style in ..\node_modules\react-native-material-dropdown\src\components\dropdown file.

And removing Animated in Animated.Text.propTypes.style in
affix/index
helper/index
label/index
of react-native-material-textfield and added import { Animated, Text} from 'react-native'; in each of above three files.